# How Can I force cookies to HttpOnly and Secure when behind load balancer using ASP.Net WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-web-api

We have our web app behind a load balancer that does SSL Off-loading which causes problems when trying to use the httpcookie element in the web.config. It seems since our web sites are running under http that either IIS or ASP.Net strips the secure flag from all of the cookies.

When using plain ASP.Net I could force all cookies to HttpOnly and Secure by adding the following code to the Global.asax

```
    void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
            {
               Response.Cookies[s].Secure = true;
               Response.Cookies[s].HttpOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

But for some reason this does not work in an pure WebApi application where we are not serving up any web pages and don't have a Global.asax file.

Is there a way I can do this using a MessageHandler or something similar?